# Estimating $\hat{p}$

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

> let $X\sim Bin(n,p)$  and $\hat{p} =\frac{X}{n}$
>
> a) Find a constant c such that $E[c\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})]=p(1-p)$

My work:
$$
\begin{align}
cE[\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})] &=E[\frac{X}{n}]-E[\frac{X^2}{n^2}]\\
&= \frac{1}{n}E[X]-\frac{1}{n^2}E[X^2] \\ 
\end{align}
$$
And I continue with $E[X] = p$ and $E[X^2] = Var(X)+E[X]^2$ but this gives me
$$
= \frac{p}{n} - \frac{1}{n^2}np(1-p)-\frac{p^2}{n^4}
$$
Which doesnt seem righ. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: $E[X]$ is $np$.

Comment: d'oh. thanks, already had the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X$ is a binomial random variable, $E[X]=np$ and $Var(X)=np(1-p)$.
Hence,
$$\frac{1}{n}E[X]-\frac{1}{n^2}E[X^{2}]=\frac{np}{n}-\frac{np(1-p)+n^{2}p^{2}}{n^2}$$
Simplifying, 
$$=p-p^{2}-\frac{1}{n}p(1-p)=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)p(1-p)$$
So we simply let $c=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{n}{n-1}$